# Как заменить одно из двух значений в словаре Python

Tags: python, ооп, dict

```
d = {}
class JOB: 
    def post_vacancy(self, company, salary, min_exp):
        self.company, self.salary, self.min_exp = company, salary, min_exp
        d[company] = salary, min_exp
    def update_salary(self, company, new_salary):
        self.company, self.new_salary = company, new_salary
        d[company] = new_salary
```

Требуется заменить значение salary на new_salary, при этом сохранив значение min_exp

Comment: `old_salary, min_exp = d[company]`  `d[company] = new_salary, min_exp`

Answer (score 1):

`d[company]` - получаем кортеж `(salary, min_exp)`

`d[company][1]` - из этого кортежа получаем значение по индексу 1. В нашем случае это min_exp

```
   def update_salary(self, company, new_salary):
        self.company, self.new_salary = company, new_salary
        d[company] = new_salary, d[company][1]
```

Но нужно предусмотреть разные ситуации - когда нет переданной `update_salary` `company`, гарантировать формат вида `(salary, min_exp)`

Comment: Спасибо большое!